# Access web service within Windows Sandbox from the host

Tags: windows, windows-sandbox

Is it possible to host a web service in Windows Sandbox and access it from the host?

That is, can I access `http://<sandbox>` if there is web service that runs in it?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Sandbox is a temporary operating system that goes away on restart or shutdown, which is always inevitable at some point.

I have used Windows Sandbox and there is no native way to either install a web server in it or access it from outside (if some way was found to install the web server and maintain it).

You need to use an ordinary virtual machine (connected via NAT or Bridged Networking) to accomplish what you wish. This will work.

Comment: I can run web server OK within it (dotnet kestrel). I supposed its not possible to access it but thought maybe there is some hack.